# Is it possible to change the group that a user belongs in the front-end?

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2

**A little background:**

- The website runs on Craft v.3 Pro and Commerce v.2 Pro
- The user can register as a member from the front-end.
- They will be able to select only one of 3 different groups to register to. (eg. Bronze, Silver, Gold member)
- None of the groups will allow access to the CP.
- The group type will control what content they can access on the website and what kind of discounts they can get on the online store.

Is it possible to let the user switch between those 3 different membership types via the front-end?

If this is not possible out of the box, then is it possible by writing a plug-in or via an existing one?

What is the recommended way to achieve this type of functionality?